# Problemas with Python3 and http.client

Tags: python-3.x, httpclient

I have a problem with Python3.

I am trying to get the http status code like "200 OK"of a server reading the paths from a file and typing the url.

**It works with some servers** but with other ones I have the problem below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple_program.py", line 55, in <module>
    main()
  File "simple_program.py", line 52, in main
    parser(url)
  File "simple_program.py", line 27, in parser
    r1 = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/http/client.py", line 1143, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/http/client.py", line 354, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/http/client.py", line 336, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
  http.client.BadStatusLine: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
```

This is the part of the code which fails.

```
                    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(url)
                    conn.request("GET", path)
                    r1 = conn.getresponse()
                    conn.close()
                    print(url_path, r1.status, r1.reason)
                    print("\n")
```

Could you help me?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the server is not sending the HTTP status line... This sounds very weird, but there's a way to validate this.

You can use `curl` to dump the response headers. For example on my website:

```
$ curl -I http://aspyct.org
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2013 15:42:16 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 10645
Last-Modified: Sat, 20 Jul 2013 14:09:39 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Thu, 21 Nov 2013 15:42:15 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

What is it for you? If none, maybe the server itself does not respect HTTP protocol.

In that case there's probably not much you can do about it with the python stdlib. You may want to implement you own request handler, and use it on these servers.

Comment: Try with `curl -v` instead then. Also, can you dump the headers you're sending with your request?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

When I execute the `curl -I` and with `curl -v` commands a get the same...

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

but with my program I get 

http.client.BadStatusLine: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">

If I create the code in python2 I have no problems...

Comment: Which leads to the other part of my comment: can you indicate your request headers? Or maybe can you even provide the address of the server which has this behavior ?

Comment: `code HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 22 Nov 2013 08:24:31 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Set-Cookie: SESS7db3aa03ecde475527f0; expires=Sun, 15-Dec-2013 11:57:51 GMT; path=/; domain=.****.es; HttpOnly
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 22 Nov 2013 08:24:31 GMT
Cache-Control: store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

Comment: These are the response headers. Can you please provide the *request* headers? It should start with `GET …` if you're sending a GET request.